# Url to {replace} @ space with Hyphen in MVC-Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am using ASP.NET MVC Razor C# with Attribute Routes

In my Category form when I click on Edit. it opens the Url like below:

http://localhost:38812/Category/Database%20Design

I am trying to change the Url like below

http://localhost:38812/Category/Database-Design

Here the problem is, when I go to database to search for the category based details..it does not search because there is no category with the name of Database-Design. It exist as Database Design with space.

Is there any way to not include the Id in Url and so we can also achieve the below Url? :

http://localhost:38812/Category/Database-Design

Comment: What is wrong with http://localhost:38812/Category/Database%20Design?

Comment: In your controller method, use `string.Replace()` to replace the hyphen with a space and use the result for the search parameter

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Sir, I just modified the Query Title and now we can see  hyphen and some special chars. Here question is: What if the category name already contains the hyphen and other special chars. How can I manage those ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create an extra column (`Sanitized`) in your `Category` table

something like below

```
 ID | Name            | Sanitized
---------------------------------------
  1 | Database Design | database-design
  2 | ABC-DEF_HIJ     | abc-def-hij
  3 | !Hello World!   | hello-world
  4 | happy~~feet     | happy-feet
```

By doing this way, Url and database query should make use of the `Sanitized` column

You wouldn't worry about what to replace with hyphen
and it's all customisable.

Comment: Upvoted and Accepted. Great suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is Decode the Url. You can do this by using

```
string decodedUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url)
```

That will replace the %20 and return it back to how it was originally.

You can read more about this here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx